в Django CKEditor html не интерпретируется в код

После добавления записи с помощью формы CKEditor, html верстка отображается, как текст и не интерпретируется в код
**models.py**
class New(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(
        verbose_name=_('Название'),
        validators=[
            MinLengthValidator(1, _("Название не может быть пустым."))
        ]
    )
    description = models.TextField(
        verbose_name=_('Описание'),
        validators=[
            MinLengthValidator(1, _("Описание не может быть пустым."))
        ]
    )

    author = models.ForeignKey(
        'User',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name=_('Автор')
    )
    date_of_create = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Дата создания новости')
    is_archived = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Архивирован")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.date_of_create:
            self.date_of_create = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())

        super(New, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    # def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #     """ Переопределяет метод удаления, помечая объект как архивированный вместо удаления. """
    #     self.is_archived = True
    #     self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        """ Возвращает строковое представление объекта Hotel. """
        archived_status = " (Архивировано)" if self.is_archived else ""
        return f"{self.title}, Автор: {self.author}{archived_status}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Новость"
        verbose_name_plural = "Новости"

    def get_view_count(self):
        """
        Возвращает количество просмотров для данной статьи
        """
        return self.views.count()

**views.py**
def create_new(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new = form.save()
            new.save()
            return redirect('new')
    else:
        form = NewForm()
    return render(request, 'create_new.html', {'form': form})

**forms.py**
class NewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = New
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'author']
        widgets = {
            'title': CKEditorWidget(),
            'description': CKEditorWidget(),
        }



**create_new.html**
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" %}"></script>
{% block title %} Добавление новости {% endblock title %}


{% block content %}
<form method="post">
    {{ form.media }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p|safe }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}

